# Django query for multiple fields with list values

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have below Django model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    post_url = models.URLField(max_length = 200, blank = True)
    post_tier = models.ForeignKey(Tiers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null= True)
    post_tier_value = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
```

I have `author_list = [author1@gmail.com, author2@gmail.com]` and `tier_value_list = [2000,3000]`. I want to query in the above model for `(author = author1@gmail.com and post_tier_value <= 2000)` or `(author = author2@gmail.com and post_tier_value <= 3000)`.

Can someone help me how to make query for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`Q()`** operator

```
from django.db.models import Q

author_list = ['author1@gmail.com', 'author2@gmail.com']
tier_value_list = [2000, 3000]
query = Q()
for author, value in zip(author_list, tier_value_list):
    query = query | Q(author=author, post_tier_value__lte=value)

Post.objects.filter(query)
```

**Note:** I have used **`author__email`** which is a ***nested lookup*** since the `author_list` contain the email_ids